# Does Rails support link_to with method post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I have a rails `link_to` that I want to run a post with...

```
<%= link_to 'Unfollow', follows_path(user_id: u.id), method: :delete, class: 'text-right btn btn-primary' %>
```

The route for it:

```
  resource :follows, only: %i[create destroy]
```

However, when I click it runs as a get:

```
Started GET "/follows?user_id=1" for ::1 at 2020-05-27 00:51:00 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/follows"):
```

I have checked multiple questions on SO on using `link_to`as a post method to no avail. I believe it is worth mentioning that the HTML rendered as:

```
<a class="text-right btn btn-primary" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/follows?user_id=8">Unfollow</a>
```

However, I eventually resigned to using a small form like so:

```
<% if !(current_user.is_following?(@user)) %>
  <% @follow = Follow.new %>
  <%= form_for (@follow) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <% @follow = Follow.new %>
  <%= form_for (@follow), method: :delete do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Is it no longer possible to use post methods with `link_to` or has the syntax changed?

Answer (score 1):

put follow_path with singular not follows

```
<%= link_to 'Unfollow', follow_path(user_id: u.id), method: :delete, class: 'text-right btn btn-primary' %>
```

Comment: Sorry, no that didn't work, I was still running my form from another page. What you suggested returns an `undefined_method` error.